# Microsoft.VisualBasic как использовать несколько звуков одновременно?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-basic

Использую *Microsoft.VisualBasic* для воспроизведения звука. Но при активации другого звука, отключается другой. `MediaPlayer` не подходит т.к у меня проблемы с его подключением. Есть ли способ на *Microsoft.VisualBasic*?

Comment: Есть библиотека NAudio, написанная на C#, попробуйте её.

Comment: Попробовать то можно, но меня интересует именно Microsoft.VisualBasic. Если на нём нету способов, то тогда уже буду рассматривать другие библиотеки, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: Так поставьте её из нугета, да пользуйтесь. Какая разница, какой язык.

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно помогло